# How do I get the currently used locale from Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following form.

```
<form id="langForm" action="" method="get">
    <select name="lang" id="lang" class="styled" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="pl" ${param.lang == 'pl' ? 'selected' : ''} >PL</option>
        <option value="en" ${param.lang == 'en' ? 'selected' : ''} >EN</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Spring MVC sets the language parameter and takes care about i18n/l10n. I would like to change the `${param.lang}` to let it obtain the current user language from session by Spring MVC, because the `lang` parameter is not necessarily present in every request. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If it's the response header, why do you need to *get* the value in the servlet?

Comment: You're using some framework for i18n/l10n. You have to request it from the framework, not from HTTP/Servlet. A detailed answer is impossible to give as long as you don't tell which framework you're using for i18n/l10n.

Comment: I'm using a spring mvc, and I don't know how to get a value of language in controller mapping method

Comment: I'd recommend to reframe this question as "How do I get the currently used locale from Spring MVC?".

Comment: Reframing is not only editing the title. I've helped you to change the question so that it asks what you *really needed* (as far as I understand). Please review and edit when necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the fallowing in your xml configuration:

```
...

<mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
            p:paramName="lang" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver"
        id="localeResolver" p:cookieName="locale" />
...
```

Replace you code by:

```
<form id="langForm" action="" method="get">
    <select name="lang" id="lang" class="styled" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="pl">PL</option>
        <option value="en">EN</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

With this configuration the locale selected wil be save in cookies browser.

don't forget namespaces  at the begin of file in  tag :
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
and

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd

tutorial [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/07/spring-3-mvc-internationalization-i18n-localization-tutorial-example.html)